# how to install portable virtual box on LINUX HOST

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive

I'm looking for info on Google. I can only find solutions on how to do it on a Windows host, but I want it done backward. I run Linux (Ubuntu) and I want to create a portable virtual machine to install Windows 8.1 on it (using VirtualBox) to carry on a flash drive. Any one knows how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to export the VM to a flash drive, or do you want to install VirtualBox to the flash drive?

Comment: install it into the flash in a way i can open it in different computers just carrying the flash memory

Comment: This is not going to be easy to do. VirtualBox requires kernel drivers to be present - it's not as simple as copying some files to the drive (even on Windows, the portable version consists of software to load and unload the drivers, and therefore needs administrative privileges). It would probably be easier to install VirtualBox natively and carry only the VM on your flash drive.

Comment: If you will be using the VM on different hosts frequently, it would be a good idea to [place your working directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95616/portable-virtual-machine) on the flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a linux persistent USB, and install Vitual Box to it. (make sure it is a big usb) Then you can run it on any computer.